# Is stiffness of a beam the product of Young's modulus and second moment of area?

Tags: terminology, material-science, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

Is stiffness of a beam the product of Young's modulus and second moment of area? I read online that stiffness of a beam is function of the product of young's modulus and second moment of area. I cannot find any reference of the exact equation. Is it just the product of the young's modulus and the second moment of area or is there anything more? I don't know the deflection of the beam, I only know its young modulus and its second moment of area and I want to compare two beams based on that. How can I do it?

Comment: Lookup "flexural rigidity" for beams.

Answer (score 3):

Take a clamped beam of length $\ell$. The deflection due to an end load is

$$ \delta = \frac{F \ell^3}{3 E I}$$

The stiffness (in terms of force/displacement) is $$ k =\frac{3 E I}{\ell^3} $$

where $E I$ is the young's modulus times the area moment. So the stiffness is proportional to what is called *flexural rigidity*. It represents the part of the stiffness that is dependent on the cross sectional shape and the material.